# Trigger loadcache over xml file

Tags: caching, ignite, persistent-storage

I am trying to create a 3.rd party persistent store and I have done with the conf. The only problem is: the samples are showing this like I need to write code in order to get the cache instance and then I need to call loadcache function.

Is there a way to call it over config(default-config.xml)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might need is a Ignite LifecycleBean, which can be configured inside of XML file. More information here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ignite-life-cycle#section-lifecyclebean

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it can be done via XML configuration file. You have to call `IgniteCache.loadCache()` explicitly.